# Отступы между блоками в bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

Всем привет. Как сделать между блоками отступ?

Вот что у меня есть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно чтобы было так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мой код:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 blocks-politic">
            <?= Html::img(Url::to('/uploads/politics/9859aeecafa753b42b613e63d4872b54_presydent_ua.jpg'), ['alt' => '9859aeecafa753b42b613e63d4872b54_presydent_ua.jpg']) ?>
            <p class="politic-name">Петро Порошенко</p>
            <p class="politic-position">Президент</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 blocks-politic">
            <?= Html::img(Url::to('/uploads/politics/a521671ed3207abf6735d35b1b9a9b0a_800px-Yulia_Tymoshenko_2018_Vadim_Chuprina.jpg'), ['alt' => '9859aeecafa753b42b613e63d4872b54_presydent_ua.jpg']) ?>
            <p class="politic-name">Петро Порошенко</p>
            <p class="politic-position">Президент</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 blocks-politic">
            <?= Html::img(Url::to('/uploads/politics/9859aeecafa753b42b613e63d4872b54_presydent_ua.jpg'), ['alt' => '9859aeecafa753b42b613e63d4872b54_presydent_ua.jpg']) ?>
            <p class="politic-name">Петро Порошенко</p>
            <p class="politic-position">Президент</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 blocks-politic">
            <?= Html::img(Url::to('/uploads/politics/a521671ed3207abf6735d35b1b9a9b0a_800px-Yulia_Tymoshenko_2018_Vadim_Chuprina.jpg'), ['alt' => '9859aeecafa753b42b613e63d4872b54_presydent_ua.jpg']) ?>
            <p class="politic-name">Петро Порошенко</p>
            <p class="politic-position">Президент</p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задать внешние отступы блокам .col-lg-3 не получится (вернее, получится, но тогда это сломает сетку), поэтому внутри них лучше сформировать отдельные блоки .blocks-politic и уже работать с ними:

```css
.blocks-politic {
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px gray;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="blocks-politic">
      <img src="https://mtdata.ru/u21/photoDC4B/20597497837-0/original.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" />
      <p class="politic-name">Володимир Зеленський</p>
      <p class="politic-position">Президент</p>
    </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="blocks-politic">
      <img src="https://mtdata.ru/u21/photoDC4B/20597497837-0/original.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" />
      <p class="politic-name">Володимир Зеленський</p>
      <p class="politic-position">Президент</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="blocks-politic">
      <img src="https://mtdata.ru/u21/photoDC4B/20597497837-0/original.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" />
      <p class="politic-name">Володимир Зеленський</p>
      <p class="politic-position">Президент</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="blocks-politic">
      <img src="https://mtdata.ru/u21/photoDC4B/20597497837-0/original.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" />
      <p class="politic-name">Володимир Зеленський</p>
      <p class="politic-position">Президент</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```